# Call to a member function links() on array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am receiving this error while trying to create pagination in laravel.

> ErrorException in 1e886a45102a3e4898f23b52cd7ca771 line 396: Call to a
>   member function links() on array (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\soulfy_repo\framework\resources\views\soulfy\setting.blade.php)

```
line 396:  <?php echo e($themes->links()); ?>
```

HomeController.php

```
public function getBackgroundTheme()
{

    $query = DB::table('theme_background');

    if (request()->has('menu')) {
        $theme = DB::table('kategori_name')->where('kategori_theme', request('menu'))->first();

        $query = $query->where('kategori_id', $theme->kategori_id);
    }

    //$model = $query->get();
    $theme = $query->paginate(4);

    return view('soulfy.setting', [
        'themes'=>$theme,
        'user' => auth()->user(),
    ]);


    // return redirect('/home/setting' . 
}
```

setting.blade.php

```
        <table>

    @if(isset($themes))
        @foreach($themes as $m)

            <tr>
                <td><img width="100px" height="100px" src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/theme/{{$m->pic_name}}.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img width="100px" height="100px" src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/theme/{{$m->pic_name}}.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img width="100px" height="100px" src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/theme/{{$m->pic_name}}.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><div class="box"><input type="checkbox" name="pic" value=""></div></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="pic" value=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="pic" value=""></td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach

        {{ $themes->links() }}
    @endif


</table>
```

Comment: try to comment the `if` block : this one  `if (request()->has('menu')) {
        $theme = DB::table('kategori_name')->where('kategori_theme', request('menu'))->first();

        $query = $query->where('kategori_id', $theme->kategori_id);
    }` and see if it will work

Comment: Still having the same error message

Answer (score 1):

```
 $theme = DB::table('kategori_name')->where('kategori_theme', request('menu'))->paginate(PAGELIMIT);
```

> Use This In Your Home Controller. Instead Of first();
>   And Define This In Your Routes : **define('PAGELIMIT','4');**